# Cellulose acid hydrolysis

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, analytical-chemistry, reactivity, extraction

Recently i tried to hydrolyse some 10g of cellulose with 50ml of 75% H2SO4. Right after adding the acid, the entire solution turned blue black. With no heat applied.